# How to reverse level index of array using foreach in php?

Tags: php, foreach

I'm using PHP on foreach function

```
$arr = array(array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10));
       foreach($arr as $item){
             var_dump($item);
       }
```

And here is my result

```
array (size=10)
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 2
  2 => int 3
  3 => int 4
  4 => int 5
  5 => int 6
  6 => int 7
  7 => int 8
  8 => int 9
  9 => int 10
```

But I want to revers from high to small back

```
array (size=10)
  0 => int 10
  1 => int 9
  2 => int 8
  3 => int 7
  4 => int 8
  5 => int 9
  6 => int 4
  7 => int 5
  8 => int 2
  9 => int 1
```

How can I do

Comment: [rsort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) is the function you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array_reverse() :

```
$arr = array(array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10));
       foreach($arr as $item){
             var_dump(array_reverse ($item));
       }
```

See [result](https://eval.in/479611)

Answer (score 1):

You could use PHPs reverse array sort (rsort). See the [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php)

```
$arr = array(array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10));
rsort($arr);
       foreach($arr as $item){
             var_dump($item);
       }
```